# RecycleView - view a particular position list on the screen and change it after every 1 hour

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to view a particular item on the screen. Example: I have a list of 10 items in my recycleview from [0 - 9]. Now when I launch the activity all the items will be shown on screen in order of [0,1,2,3,4,...] (horizontally or vertically) and the 0th item will be seen first on the screen and when I scroll then the 1st, 2nd, 3rd ... item will be seen on the screen. 
What I want is when I launch the activity based on the current time item should show on screen like from 8 am - 9 am 0th item on the screen, from 9 am - 10 am 1st item on the screen, from 10 am - 11 am 2nd item on the screen and so on but when I scroll then the other items should also be visible like currently if 3rd item is visible on screen and if I scroll left then 4th, 5th ... items should be visible or if I scroll right then 2nd, 1st, 0th item should be visible. Please help me in finding a solution to this.

Comment: post some code to understand

Comment: you can used  recyclerView.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(position) set the position by your items.

Comment: override method getItemViewType() in adapter and getItemId() with returning position.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to put check on the basis of your current time . With calendar instance you will get the current time .

Once you have time , say its 10:40 am  ,check if (time is between 10 or 11) , if this comes out to be true . Then scroll to that specific position

recycler.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(youPositionInTheAdapter).

As a reminder , Before scroll do check your list size . Your position shouldn't be equal or greater than list size .